# Incorrect declension of possessive adjectives in DW manuscript?

Tags: adjective, declension, adjective-ending, possessive, wechselpraeposition

In this [text from DW](https://learngerman.dw.com/de/ein-fu%C3%9Fweg-mit-hindernissen/l-64285122/lm), I noticed this sentence:

> Deshalb fügen sich die meisten **in ihr Leid** an dieser Kreuzung, auch wenn den wenigsten einleuchtet, warum ihnen die Stadt das antut.

To my knowledge, it should be "in ihrem Leid"? Leid is neutral (i.e. Das Leid), and "ihr" is a possessive adjective for "sie"; in this case, at dative position; thus, "ihrem" ([link](https://germanwithlaura.com/possessive-pronouns/)).

---Updated:

- "ihr" is a **possessive adjective**, not possessive pronoun.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The case is determined by the preposition “in”. Now “in” is a two-way preposition, it can take either accusative or dative, depending on the meaning. In this case, it is “sich in etw (Akkusativ) fügen“. Compare the examples 3(b) in the [entry for “fügen” at DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/f%C3%BCgen).

Comment: This is a prepositional verb, and the usual movement rule taught to students is not applicable with them. More often than not the preposition takes the accusative, but there are enough dative exceptions that you can't call this a rule and you often have to memorize which case to use for each prepositional verb.